# Save and find within same transaction

Tags: spring-data

I am using `Jboss JTS` as the transaction manager with spring data.

When I try to,
1.  Save an entity
2.  Find same entity

within the same transaction, the repository returns null (for both JPA and Cassandra).

However if it's in different transactions, then it works fine.
Any suggestions on how to proceed ?
Is this the intended behavior  or is it supposed to retrieve from the transaction area ?

```
transactionManager.beginTransaction();
repo.save(entity);
Entity entityFound = repo.findOne(id);
Assert.assertTrue(entityFound != null); //fails
```

Here is my test,

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SDPTest {

@Autowired 
LaptopRepository repo;

@Autowired
TransactionManager txManager;

@Test
public void test() {
    try {

        final long id = 400;


        txManager.begin();
        LaptopEntity entity = TestEntityFactory.generateTestLaptopEntity();
        entity.setId(id);

        repo.save(entity);

        LaptopEntity foundEntity = repo.findOne(id); // should find within transactional scope ? 
        Assert.notNull(foundEntity); // fails
        txManager.commit();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The JBOSS TS transaction bean configuration,

```
<bean id="jbossUserTransaction"
    class="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.UserTransactionImple"/>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="jbossTransactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="userTransaction">
        <ref bean="jbossUserTransaction" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

The entity factory configuration, `ConfigurationOracle.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("xdm-sdp-oracle.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="${xdm.sdp.oracle.repo-package}", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactoryOrcl1")
public class ConfigurationOracle {
  @Autowired 
  Environment env;

  public DataSource buildOracleDataSource() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();

    dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jpa.oracle.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jpa.oracle.password"));
    dataSource.setURL(env.getProperty("jpa.oracle.url"));

    dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
    dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean(name="entityManagerFactoryOrcl1")
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryOrcl() throws SQLException {
    final DataSource oracleDataSource = buildOracleDataSource();
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName(env.getProperty("jpa.oracle.persistence-name"));
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(oracleDataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("xdm.sdp.oracle.entity-package"));

    PersistenceUnitPostProcessor processor = new PersistenceUnitPostProcessor() {
        public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(MutablePersistenceUnitInfo unitInfo) {
            unitInfo.setJtaDataSource(oracleDataSource);
        }
    };
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors(processor);

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
  }
}
```

The entity class,

```
@Entity
public class LaptopEntity extends DataEntity implements Persistable<String> {


private String name;
private String macID;

@Id
private String machineID;
private long memoryCapacity;
private long storageCapacity;

private double powerDraw;
private double batteryStandbyTime;

private boolean isShared;
private boolean webcamPresent;
private boolean fingerprintSensorPresent;

private boolean isNewEntity;



public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMacID() {
    return macID;
}
public void setMacID(String macID) {
    this.macID = macID;
}
public boolean isShared() {
    return isShared;
}
public void setShared(boolean isShared) {
    this.isShared = isShared;
}
public long getMemoryCapacity() {
    return memoryCapacity;
}
public void setMemoryCapacity(long memoryCapacity) {
    this.memoryCapacity = memoryCapacity;
}
public long getStorageCapacity() {
    return storageCapacity;
}
public void setStorageCapacity(long storageCapacity) {
    this.storageCapacity = storageCapacity;
}


public double getPowerDraw() {
    return powerDraw;
}
public void setPowerDraw(double powerDraw) {
    this.powerDraw = powerDraw;
}
public double getBatteryStandbyTime() {
    return batteryStandbyTime;
}
public void setBatteryStandbyTime(double batteryStandbyTime) {
    this.batteryStandbyTime = batteryStandbyTime;
}
public boolean isWebcamPresent() {
    return webcamPresent;
}
public void setWebcamPresent(boolean webcamPresent) {
    this.webcamPresent = webcamPresent;
}
public boolean isFingerprintSensorPresent() {
    return fingerprintSensorPresent;
}
public void setFingerprintSensorPresent(boolean fingerprintSensorPresent) {
    this.fingerprintSensorPresent = fingerprintSensorPresent;
}


public int compareTo(LaptopEntity machine) {
    return this.machineID.compareTo(machine.getMachineID());
}
public Class<? extends CrudRepository> getRepoClass() {
    return LaptopRepository.class;
}
public String getMachineID() {
    return machineID;
}
public void setMachineID(String machineID) {
    this.machineID = machineID;
}
public String getId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return machineID;
}
public boolean isNew() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return isNewEntity;
}
public boolean isNewEntity() {
    return isNewEntity;
}
public void setNewEntity(boolean isNewEntity) {
    this.isNewEntity = isNewEntity;
}




}
```

The repository,

```
public interface LaptopRepository extends JpaRepository<LaptopEntity, Long> { 

}
```

And finally, the spring configuration file, `SpringConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:jboss-springContext.xml","classpath:property-placeholder.xml"})
@Import({ConfigurationOracle.class})
@ComponentScan
public class SpringConfig {}
```

Comment: It seems I can't edit the question, this being a new account.   
I do `transactionManager.commitTransaction()` and normal transaction with commit and rollback works fine.

Comment: How do you get `id`? Is is supposed to be auto-generated or are you supplying your own identifiers?

Comment: @manish It's a test. So, it's saved beforehand in the entity.

Comment: Please show us your full code, a working sample, if possible. It is impossible to see comment otherwise.

Comment: How is the `id` field in `Laptop` class annotated? It is quite possible that the entity is not being saved at all. The test method is also structured weirdly (not utilizing any Spring plumbing). I would structure the test class [like this](https://gist.github.com/manish-in-java/6207efaa546738bca46a828ca664beac#file-sdptest-java).

Comment: @manish I've updated with the entity class and structured the test class, having the same trouble though.

Comment: `long` (or any primitive type for that matter) is not a good data type for the primary key field for a managed entity as the JPA provider will have trouble determining when an entity needs to be inserted. If you have the option of checking the SQL logs, you will find that the application is issuing an `UPDATE ...` instead of `INSERT`. This is why nothing is being inserted into the database when `save` is called.

Comment: @manish I changed the `id(machineID)` to `String` and I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: The problem is not only that you had a primitive type for the primary key but also that you are manually specifying the identifier and the JPA provider is unable to figure out that you are doing this for a new entity instance. Simply changing the data type of the key will not help. You need to annotate the identifier according to how your application will work in production with your database (Oracle). The annotations vary for each database and I haven't used Oracle in a while to guide you correctly.

Comment: Also see the [official Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites) which clarifies that if the value of the primary key field is set to anything other than `null`, the entity is assumed not to be new (so an `INSERT` will not be fired). The document also suggests how you can override the default behaviour by implementing the `Persistable` interface.

Comment: @manish I've used the `Persistable` interface and Hibernate is calling `INSERT` on commit according to the SQL logs. But within the transaction it's still null.  
  
Also I'm confused about database specific annotation, isn't the whole point of JPA to be db agnostic ?

Comment: JPA is indeed database agnostic. However, your approach to managing primary key values is not since different databases support different primary key generation strategies and then you may choose to employ your custom strategy altogether. Therefore, different configuration settings are required based on the database chosen and the primary key generation strategy. You are stuck because you have picked up a tricky way of generating primary keys in your tests without first understanding JPA or how ORMs work.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41635777) is a sample project that demonstrates that records can be saved and retrieved within the same transaction just fine. It uses H2, an in-memory database and automatic primary key generation but the basic process questioned in the post above is proven nevertheless.

Comment: @manish, I have fixed the issue. I had a wrong configuration in my xml file, I had used post processing for setting the datasource as JTA. It's working fine now. 
Thank you for providing the example which I was able to confirm and your example on GitHub for JBoss TS and Spring Data. I was able to work out from that.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I'll try to answer here for people arriving here.

The reason is simple. In your transaction you are saving your object `repo.save(entity);` and retrieving here right after `Entity entityFound = repo.findOne(id);`, but after your `save` the objet is not in the database. You need to commit your transaction before you can retrieve the object.

You are looking in the database before actually saving the object. If you want this to work you need to commit the `save` and open a new transaction to make the `findOne` work.